# Is it possible to catch a canceled page submit or a cancel confirm box in javascript or oracle apex 5.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex

I am currently do a form page on a tabular form and I detect when a change has been made to the form. If a change has been made to a form and you submit the page (either cancel button or choosing a filter), a confirm box appears which asks you if you want to continue since you will lose all unsaved changes. Now if the user selects Ok, he continues with the page submit. If the user selects cancel the page submission stops. This is where I need help because the filter that starts the page submit process does not go back to its original value, and the tabular form does not filter.

Where I am at:
I am currently getting the original value of the filter before the page submit request. I think I just need a function that can be called on a cancel of the page submission/cancel on the confirm pop up in order to set the filter back to its original value. Does anyone know if this is a possibility or a different way of thinking?

Any thoughts are helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I make the onsubmit function return false if I want to cancel the submit.

```
<form name='DataForm' action='nextpage.php' method='post'
onsubmit='return Ask()'>
</form>
```

The javascript will look like

```
function Ask() {
  return confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the changes?");
}
```